# How to simplify my routes on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is it possible to make the following code more elegant ?

I wrote some action in cart controller

```
  resources :carts do     
  end


  get "cart/search" => "carts#search"
  get "cart/search_book" => "carts#search_book"
  #search user
  get "cart/search_user" => "carts#search_user"
  get "cart/search_book_by_sn" => "carts#search_book_by_sn"
  get "cart/load_user" => "carts#load_user"
```

Answer (score 3):

Would not it be better to have only the search method on routes and work with parameters.
That would leave their routes cleaner.

Eg

In the method on model:

```
def search(params)

end
```

In your controller:

```
def index
   Model.search(params)
end
```

and in your routes:

```
resources :cart do
   collection do
       get :search
   end
end
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use collection for routes

```
 resources :carts do          
   collection do 
     get :search
     get :search_book
     get :search_user
     get :search_book_by_sn
     get :load_user 
   end   
 end
```

It probably can different routes url

Check `rake routes` and use the urls generated

For more info [routes guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: To make it more readable and short you can use comma separated values. eg. `get :search, :search_book, :search_user, :search_book_by_sn, :load_user`. Also, you can remove the `collection do..end` block by appending `, on: :collection` to previous get method.

Comment: @ManojMonga : +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
resources :cart do
  collection do
    get "search" => "carts#search"
    get "search_book" => "carts#search_book"
    get "search_user" => "carts#search_user"
    get "search_book_by_sn" => "carts#search_book_by_sn"
    get "load_user" => "carts#load_user"
  end
end
```

I d't think, you are expecting this, But above code will simplify your routes.